# How can I check when animator state has finished playing animation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AnimFlyertransportationController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject JetFlame;
    public bool turnOffOn = false;
    public bool land = false;

    private Animator[] animators;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        TurnAllAnimtorsOff(transform, turnOffOn);

        if (turnOffOn)
        {
            JetFlame.SetActive(true);
        }
        else
        {
            JetFlame.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

private void TurnAllAnimtorsOff(Transform root, bool onOff)
    {
        animators = root.GetComponentsInChildren<Animator>(true);

        foreach (Animator a in animators)
        {
            if (onOff)
            {
                a.enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                a.enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnValidate()
    {
        TurnAllAnimtorsOff(transform, turnOffOn);

        if(land == true && turnOffOn)
        {
            animators[0].Play("Anim_Flyer_Land");

            TurnAllAnimtorsOff(transform, false);
            JetFlame.SetActive(false);
            turnOffOn = false;

            
            land = false;
        }
        else if(land == false && turnOffOn)
        {
            animators[0].Play("Anim_Flyer_Takeoff");
        }

        if (JetFlame) JetFlame.SetActive(turnOffOn);
    }
}

// Anim_Flyer_Takeoff

// Anim_Flyer_Land
```

At this place I need to check if the "Anim_Flyer_Land" animation finished playing then set everything to false :

```
if(land == true && turnOffOn)
            {
                animators[0].Play("Anim_Flyer_Land");
    
                TurnAllAnimtorsOff(transform, false);
                JetFlame.SetActive(false);
                turnOffOn = false;
    
                
                land = false;
            }
```

Now it's setting everything to false before the animation has finished playing.

The main goal is to use two flags or one is even better when true set everything to true the animators and the flame the default state machine state is the Anim_Flyer_Takeoff then when setting the flag to false first play the land animation and then turn off disable everything and then if flag is true again first enable everything and play the take off.

Screenshot of the animator controller :

[image: Default state is the take off]

The idea is to make a flag for take off/land

I tried this the checking script if the animation still playing :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CheckAnimationEnd : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject _animator;
    public string animStateName;

    private Animator _ani;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        _ani = _animator.GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (animStateName != null && animStateName != "" && _ani != null)
            IsPlayingAnimation();
    }

    public bool IsPlayingAnimation()
    {
        bool IsOffLand = false;

        if (_ani != null)
        {
            if (!_ani.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName(animStateName))
            {
                IsOffLand = true;
            }
            else
            {
                IsOffLand = false;
            }
        }

        return IsOffLand;
    }
}
```

And then :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AnimFlyertransportationController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject JetFlame;
    public CheckAnimationEnd checkAnimEnd;
    public bool turnOffOn = false;

    private Animator[] animators;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        TurnAllAnimtorsOff(transform, turnOffOn);

        if (turnOffOn)
        {
            JetFlame.SetActive(true);
        }
        else
        {
            JetFlame.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

private void TurnAllAnimtorsOff(Transform root, bool onOff)
    {
        animators = root.GetComponentsInChildren<Animator>(true);

        foreach (Animator a in animators)
        {
            if (onOff)
            {
                a.enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                a.enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnValidate()
    {
        TurnAllAnimtorsOff(transform, turnOffOn);

        if (JetFlame) JetFlame.SetActive(turnOffOn);

        Land();
        TakeOff();
    }

    private void Land()
    {
        if (turnOffOn == false)
        {
            checkAnimEnd.animStateName = "Anim_Flyer_Takeoff";

            animators[0].Play("Anim_Flyer_Land");

            if (checkAnimEnd.IsPlayingAnimation())
            {
                TurnAllAnimtorsOff(transform, false);
                JetFlame.SetActive(false);
                turnOffOn = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private void TakeOff()
    {
        if(turnOffOn)
        {
            checkAnimEnd.animStateName = "Anim_Flyer_Land";

            animators[0].Play("Anim_Flyer_Takeoff");

            if (checkAnimEnd.IsPlayingAnimation())
            {
                TurnAllAnimtorsOff(transform, true);
                JetFlame.SetActive(true);
                turnOffOn = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but everything is messed now. when I set the TurnOffOn to be true the spacecraft start from up and land and then when set it false it's taking off and everything turn on/off the animators and fire I messed all the flags and both scripts.

Comment: You can use animation event or StateMachineBehaviour.

Answer (score 0):

you can add (animation event) at the end of the animation state then put all the commands that you want on the animation event's function.